# Batch file to process filenames ending in specific characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file that calls three files from a particular folder each ending in a different set of characters. I can map the path to the folder no problem and the code works, but I can't create a wildcard before the three specific ending characters I am looking for. The filename lengths in the folder are variable and I won't know these as they are created by a previous batch file, but all end with the specific three characters (_BX.tif). I used the following code but it does not recognize the * before the _B4.tif for example, so it actually prints the * in the cmd line.

```
for /d %%a in ("%mypath%\*") do (
script.exe "%%a\*_B4.tif" "%%a\*_B3.tif" "%%a\*_B2.tif" "%%a\*_output.tif"
)
```

Is there an alternative way to do this to add the wildcard so the filename can change, but it just searches the last three characters?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there only one file that matches `*_B4.tif`/`*_B3.tif`/`*_B2.tif` in each directory? Is there any other `*_B?.tif` file (e. g., `*_B1.tif`)? Is the name part before `_B?.tif` always the same per directory? I assume `*_output.tif` does not yet exist; what does `*` stand for there?

Comment: Yes, there is only one _B4.tif in the folder. There are 12 files in total, _B1.tif until _B12.tif. The name part before _B?.tif changes, but is the same for all _B1.tif until _B12.tif in the same folder. Yes, `*_output.tif` does not exist and is an output written by the script.exe. The * is that i would like to give it the same name as the text before _B?.tif

Comment: Alright, so you could try with this: `for /D %%a in ("%mypath%\*") do for /F "delims=_ eol=_" %%b in ('dir /B "%%~a\*_B4.tif"') do script.exe "%%~a\%%~b_B4.tif" "%%~a\%%~b_B3.tif" "%%~a\%%~b_B2.tif" "%%~a\%%~b_output.tif"` (supposing the each file name contains a single `_` only)

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the answer, but i have multiple `_` so it cuts the filename off at the first `_`. Can this be modified for multiple presence of `_`. Many thanks for the help with this. Actually in total i have 4 to 6 `_` in the filename before the final one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing there is only one file `*_B4.tif` in every directory, the files `*_B3.tif` and `*_B2.tif` have got the same name part `*` as `*_B4.tif` and the file `*_output.tif` should get also the same name part `*`, you could try with this, given that the `*` part does not contain any `_` on its own:

```cmd
rem // Enumerate the directories:
for /D %%a in ("%mypath%\*") do (
    rem // Get file `*_B4.tif` and extract the `*` part:
    for /F "delims=_ eol=_" %%b in ('dir /B "%%~a\*_B4.tif"') do (
        rem // Copy the `*` part from file `*_B4.tif` to all the other files:
        script.exe "%%~a\%%~b_B4.tif" "%%~a\%%~b_B3.tif" "%%~a\%%~b_B2.tif" "%%~a\%%~b_output.tif"
    )
)
```

---

In case the name part `*` of `*_B4.tif` contains `_` on its own, the approach becomes a bit more complicated:

```cmd
rem // Enumerate the directories:
for /D %%a in ("%mypath%\*") do (
    rem // Get file `*_B4.tif`:
    for %%b in ("%%~a\*_B4.tif") do (
        rem // Store currently iterated directory and name of file `*_B4.tif`:
        set "FDIR=%%~a"
        set "NAME=%%~nxb"
        rem /* Extract file name part `*` in front of the last occurring `_` by splitting
        rem    the name at every `_`, iterating through the parts, reassigning each one
        rem    to a variable, delayed by one iteration, appending to the previous value;
        rem    toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks in file names: */
        set "COLL=" & set "ITEM="
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%c in ("!NAME:_=" "!") do (
            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%d in ("!COLL!!ITEM!_") do (
                endlocal
                set "COLL=%%d"
            )
            set "ITEM=%%~c"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        rem // Copy the `*` part from file `*_B4.tif` to all the other files:
        set "NAME=!FDIR!\!COLL:~1,-1!"
        script.exe "!NAME!_B4.tif" "!NAME!_B3.tif" "!NAME!_B2.tif" "!NAME!_output.tif"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to do what you want by iterating through one of the sets of files (the ones ending _B4.tif), extracting the leading portion of the filename, and then checking if the corresponding _B3.tif and _B2.tif exist:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:main
set mypath=%1
for %%f in (%mypath%\*_B4.tif) do call :get_prefix_and_execute_script "%%f"
exit /b

REM subroutine to extract prefix of filename and call script.exe
:get_prefix_and_execute_script
set filename=%1
echo Filename: %filename%
REM extract the first portion of the filename, excluding the remaining
REM 8 characters for: _B4.tif" (also excluding trailing quotation mark).
REM Start at 1 rather than 0 to exclude the leading quotation mark.
set prefix=%filename:~1,-8%
echo Prefix: %prefix%
set B4="%prefix%_B4.tif"
set B3="%prefix%_B3.tif"
set B2="%prefix%_B2.tif"
if not exist %B3% echo %B3% not found! & exit /b
if not exist %B2% echo %B2% not found! & exit /b
REM all 3 files exist...so call script.exe
set output="%prefix%_output.tif"
script.exe %B4% %B3% %B2% %output%
echo.
exit /b
```

The for /D command is for iterating through directories, as opposed to files. So here I am just using a plain for, with no switches.

This script should handle filenames containing spaces, if that's a concern.

This script is making the assumption that the _B4.tif, _B3.tif, and _B2.tif all exist. For example if you have: file_B3.tif and file_B2.tif, but file_B4.tif does not exist, this script would be silent about that.

I don't actually have a script.exe, so I'll replace the call with:

```
echo script.exe %B4% %B3% %B2% %output%
```

Now if I create the following files:

```
echo. > test_B4.tif
echo. > test_B3.tif
echo. > test_B2.tif
echo. > "test me_B4.tif"
echo. > "test me_B3.tif"
echo. > "test me_B2.tif"
```

Note: These are not actually *.tif files, since they only contain a line break. This is just for demonstration purposes on how the script handles the filenames.

Here are also some that don't conform to the pattern:

```
echo. > abc.tif
echo. > other.txt
echo. > xyz_B4.tif
echo. > xyz_B3.tif
```

A directory listing shows:

```
06/11/2017  01:06 PM    <DIR>          .
06/11/2017  01:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/11/2017  01:06 PM                 3 abc.tif
06/11/2017  12:55 PM               851 filesets.bat
06/11/2017  01:06 PM                 3 other.txt
06/11/2017  12:49 PM                 3 test me_B2.tif
06/11/2017  12:49 PM                 3 test me_B3.tif
06/11/2017  12:49 PM                 3 test me_B4.tif
06/11/2017  12:49 PM                 3 test_B2.tif
06/11/2017  12:49 PM                 3 test_B3.tif
06/11/2017  12:49 PM                 3 test_B4.tif
06/11/2017  01:06 PM                 3 xyz_B3.tif
06/11/2017  01:06 PM                 3 xyz_B4.tif
              11 File(s)            881 bytes
```

I saved the batch script as: filesets.bat

When I run for the current directory, I get this output:

```
C:\test>filesets .
Filename: ".\test me_B4.tif"
Prefix: .\test me
script.exe ".\test me_B4.tif" ".\test me_B3.tif" ".\test me_B2.tif" ".\test me_output.tif"

Filename: ".\test_B4.tif"
Prefix: .\test
script.exe ".\test_B4.tif" ".\test_B3.tif" ".\test_B2.tif" ".\test_output.tif"

Filename: ".\xyz_B4.tif"
Prefix: .\xyz
".\xyz_B2.tif" not found!
```

Comment: I tried this and it closes the cmd window at every exit /b. It also does not seem to identify the filename. For example, the

`echo Found: %filename_prefix%` just returns "~1,-8". Also not sure where the 8 characters came from, the number prior to _BX.tif is variable. Thanks anyway for the attempt.

Comment: Hmm, "exit" should close cmd.exe, while "exit /b" either returns from the current subroutine, or terminates the script if at the top level. This is from within a batch script. "exit /b" will terminate cmd.exe executed on the command-line. The format: set variable=%other_variable:~x,-y% means: extract the substring from %other_variable% starting at character x, up until y characters before the _end_ of the string (because it is negative). The leading portion of the filename is variable in length, but the ending portion is fixed in length.

Comment: Ok, can you suggest a method to return the actual filename and i can see if i can get the code working. I can see your idea with the %filename_prefix%, but its not actually returning the filename, just `Found: ~1,-8`

Comment: @burt46 Not sure if it will help, but I edited the script to use separate variables: %filename% vs %prefix% for clarity.

Comment: Thanks Rich for the comments. The issue on my side is that the output doesnt recall the filename. With your modified script i see this. `Prefix: ~1,-8
script.exe "~1,-8_B4.tif" "~1,-8_B3.tif" "~1,-8_B2.tif" "~1,-8_output.tif"`

Comment: Still no luck. Must be something with my PC. All i see is `Prefix: ~1,-8
script.exe "~1,-8_B4.tif" "~1,-8_B3.tif" "~1,-8_B2.tif" "~1,-8_output.tif"`